# How to submit the formarray in angular in the given format?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8, angular11

While submitting the form in angular, the data should pass like given below. Inside role menu only 1st index is passing. I want all the index data to be passed on submit.

```
{
  "roleMenu":[{
    "menu":{
      "menuId": 1  
    },
    "readAccess": true,
    "writeAccess":true
  },
  {
    "menu":{
      "menuId": 2
    },
    "readAccess": true,
    "writeAccess":true
  }]

}
```

How can I achieve this?

**I have a html code:**

```
<div formArrayName="roleMenu">
            <div *ngFor="let row of postForm.get('roleMenu')['controls']; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <table matSort class="table --table-responsive table-bordered table-border-new">
                    <thead class="t-head">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center col-form-label">Menu Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center col-form-label">Read Access</th>
                            <th class="text-center col-form-label">Write Access</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let row of selectedMenuData; let i=index;">
                            <td class="text-center">{{ selectedMenuData[i]?.menuname }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <mat-checkbox formControlName="readAccess"></mat-checkbox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <mat-checkbox formControlName="writeAccess"></mat-checkbox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Typescript code:** I have the on init function and submit function

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.postForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      selectedMenuId: [[]],
      roleMenu: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          menu: this.formBuilder.group({
            menuId: [null]
          }),
          readAccess: [false],
          writeAccess: [false]
        })
      ])
    });
}

onSubmit(){
console.log(this.postForm.value);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide stackblitz?

Comment: What is understood? by me Is this what you want to achieve? - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-16-image-upload-preview-scxbzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ, in your code you shoul iterate the **"tr"** (you can also write the formArrayName in the tbody), like your forked stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-16-image-upload-preview-p9ty8s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). NOTE: Please, add an answer, not only a link in a comment

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-16-image-upload-preview-mzb5my?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: When I select menus, it should be added in the below table, then while submitting the data should pass like 
{
"roleName":"test",
"roleDescription":"",
  "roleMenu":[{
    "menu":{
      "menuId": 1  
    },
    "readAccess": true,
    "writeAccess":true
  },
  {
    "menu":{
      "menuId": 2
    },
    "readAccess": true,
    "writeAccess":true
  }]

}

Answer (score 0):

```
roleMenu: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      menu: this.formBuilder.group({
        menuId: [null]
      }),
      readAccess: [false],
      writeAccess: [false]
    })
  ])
```

it is becouse in this part of code where you preparing formArray, you added only one formgroup